# What is wrong with this piece of java code?

Tags: java

it would help me a ton if someone could find the error in this code. 
I am using Eclipse, and i am trying to make a program that spits out words/sentences at the push of a button. If you need any more information just ask.

ERROR: "if (this.boverall[a] != 0) {", ERROR message "The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int"

```
public String sentenceOverall()
  {
    ArrayList<String> toBeUsed = new ArrayList();
    for (int a = 0; a < this.soverall.length; a++) {
      if (this.boverall[a] != 0) {
        toBeUsed.add(this.soverall[a]);
      }
    }
    if (toBeUsed.size() == 2)
    {
      int sentencePattern = rand.nextInt(10);
      if (sentencePattern < 9)
      {
        String[] OverallOptions = { " The song is overall both ", " Overall, the song is both ", " This song, overall, is both ", " Your song is quite ", " I think that the song is ", " I believe that your song is both ", " Your song is without a doubt ", " In my point of view, this is ", " First of all, thank you for creating this song. This song is very ", " Judging from my position, this song is ", " Personally, I think that the song is ", " All things taken together, I would say that this song is " };
```

Comment: What is `boverall` an array of?

Comment: TO be honest im not sure. I found the kind of program i want online and i am editing it so it spits out the words that i want but before i can do that i need to fix all the code errors.

Comment: Is the only piece of code?

Comment: In many languages you can use the `0` as an implicit symbol for `false`, in java you have to write `false` to compare with an boolean.

Comment: The error is quite obvious ! You cant apply the operator != to a boolean and int. Both must be of the same type. Compiler is saying you cannot compare apples to oranges !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `boverall` is a `boolean` array. Try this instead:

```
if (this.boverall[a])
```

How did I arrive to that condition? let's see, step by step:

```
this.boverall[a] != 0     // this is wrong, can't compare int with boolean
this.boverall[a] != false // this is what you really meant to write
this.boverall[a] == true  // if it's not false, then it can only be true
this.boverall[a]          // equivalent to the above line, but shorter
```

Remember, in Java (unlike other programming languages) a `boolean` is *not* an integer, in particular `0` is not the same as `false`.

Comment: Thank you so much i am still new to this and you solved all my problems <3 thank you every body

Comment: This seems like the opposite of what the OP wants. They are testing if it is nonzero, which is usually equivalent to true.

Comment: Care to elaborate, as if (!this.boverall[a]) did not seem to work

Comment: @user3856445 the `!` was wrong, remove it. I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Still seems to be giving me that same error should i remove "!= 0" as that takes away the error but im not sure if it makes the entire code no longer work

Comment: @user3856445 of course! that's what my answer says, just copy the `if` condition as it is above - there's no `!=0` in there.